# Bootstrap 3 Navigation multi level dropdown about 5 Step

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

Need help for bootstrap multilevel menu currently usinghttp://www.bootply.com/66089
there is 3step level but required about 5 step. I had checked in Iphone and android its not working in responsive.

Thank you Advance

Comment: what is the problem? everything looks good at bootply.

Comment: required is 5tep doropdown like Menu > step1 > step3 > step4 > step4

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like below:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

```
  <div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Present Ideas</a>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown" id="accountmenu">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Account Settings<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                      <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                          <a href="#">More..</a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">3rd level</a>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                          <a href="#">More..</a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">4TH level</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">4th level</a>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                          <a href="#">More..</a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">5TH level</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">5th level</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>

                            </li>
                              <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <ul class="nav pull-right">

    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

[**http://www.bootply.com/126711**](http://www.bootply.com/126711)

Comment: I think you would need to add small screen classes for that something like col-sm-XX or col-xs-XX